# Is it possible in VBA to insert the result of a formula that is targeting and running on only the cells selected by the user?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have been having trouble getting this to work. My intention is to have a macro that I can call which will clear all of the data prior to the last instance of the character ":" off of ONLY the selected cells when the users run it. I have a similar version of this macro that works successfully for trimming selected cells but this new formula that I am attempting to run keeps debugging on the formula line for Runtime errors and do not understand why.

The original version of the formula that I am attempting to run on all of the selected cells is "=IF(ISERR(FIND(":",A6)),IF(LEN(A6)=0,"",A6),RIGHT(A6,LEN(A6)-FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(A6,":","*",LEN(A6)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A6,":",""))))))" which I have found to be functional. However I replaced the A6 cell reference with the variable reference that I believe to be the specific cell selected in the example below.

```
'Sub Sample_Evaluate()

Dim rng As Range
Dim Area As Range

'Weed out any formulas from selection
  If Selection.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    Set rng = Selection
  Else
    Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
  End If

'Trim and Clean cell values
  For Each Area In rng.Areas
Area.Value = _
        Evaluate("=IF(ISERR(FIND("":""," & Area.Address & ")),IF(LEN(" & Area.Address & ")=0,""""," & Area.Address & "),RIGHT(" & Area.Address & ",LEN(" & Area.Address & ")-FIND(""*"",SUBSTITUTE(" & Area.Address & ","":"",""*"",LEN(" & Area.Address & ")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(" & Area.Address & ","":"",""""))))))")
  
  Next area
  
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated. I personally do not want to do it this way but it is leftover code from my predecessor so getting it working is more important than having it work in the "right" way. I anticipate having to resolve this for different formulas in the future. Is there a methodology or function to do this with a changeable formula that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this with VBA, you don't need the cell formula, because you're focusing on the cell value.  This example below shows a simple way to achieve the same thing:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim cellValue As String
    cellValue = "abcd.efg.1234.987.xyz"
    
    Dim lastDot As Long
    lastDot = InStrRev(cellValue, ".")
    cellValue = Right$(cellValue, Len(cellValue) - lastDot)
End Sub
```

The `cellValue` is now ***"xyz"***.

Comment: This. Continuing to use Evaluate with a massively long formula would be like adding band-aid after band-aid on an arterial wound gushing blood.